# How can I let my rectangle spawn at different places with the random function?

Tags: c#

I want my green rectangle foodBody to spawn randomly. I know that I should use the random function for it, but I have problems with it. When I run it, nothing happens. Can you please help me out?

This is my current code:

`using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int sx = 100, sy = 100, fx = 200, fy = 200;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Rectangle foodBody;

    Random random = new Random();

    private Rectangle snakeBody;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        snakeBody = new Rectangle(sx, sy, 15, 15);
        foodBody = new Rectangle(Random.Next(this.Width), random.Next (this.Height),15,15);  //Breakpoint
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle((Brushes.Red),snakeBody);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle((Brushes.Green),foodBody);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right)
        {
            snakeBody.X += 5;
        }

        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left)
        {
           snakeBody.X -= 5;
        }
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
        {
            snakeBody.Y -= 5;
        }
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down)
        {
            snakeBody.Y += 5;
        }

        this.Refresh();
    }    

    private void moveTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

}

`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Random` object (at the top of your `Form1` class):

```
Random random = new Random();
```

Create a new `Rectangle` object using a random position within the form:

```
foodBody = new Rectangle(random.Next(this.Width), random.Next(this.Height), 15, 15);
```

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. But I probably did something wrong. Now it won't show the  snakeBody  and foodBody rectangle when I try to run it.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line where foodBody is assigned. Make sure that `this.Width` and `this.Height` are the width and height of the form.

Comment: @Hashinu - If you're having trouble with using `Random`, then _edit_ your question and include the code that uses `Random`.